# Strange error with Unity3D when using my own plugin Dll file

Tags: .net, opencv, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a AR plugin for my Unity Project based OpenCV. If i create the dll (based C++ )file target .net framework 4.0, it worked well if i didn't put it inside asset folder but outside asset folder and under my project folder. I put my dll file under the folder JwdArPlugin. [image]

But if I dragged this dll file into asset folder, it will not work and some error message would be seen from the editor . 
[image]
Then I realized that i need compile the dll file target .net framework 2.0. Finally unity recognized this dll, and i can import it to asset folder, but when i tried to run it , unity crashed. I don't know why and how to solve this kind of problem, Any Idea would be appreciated, Many thx~

"I know my word is not clear. I tried to provide more details as i can. Simple problem is , I compiled my dll file target .net framework 4.0, it works well, only i need put it under project folder and outside asset folder. Unity can not import it into asset folder. But if i compiled dll file target .net framework2.0, unity can recognize it and it could be import inside asset folder. but when the application run to the dllimport function, it crashed.
 Attached Images

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that I made a mistake before. Since Unity3D support .net frame 2.0. If i compiled my own dll with .net framework 2.0 then i need recompile OpenCV with .net framework2.0. (I am not clear here , but after i recompile opencv by using visual c++ 2008, everything is ok)